Error in Jest - "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'" after updating node to v20
Im working on a NestJS project which used to run on node v16.
After updating the node to v20 and triggering Jest tests for certain app Im getting the following error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' which reflecting on this line of code - import { GetParametersCommand, SSMClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-ssm'
My jest.config file look like this:
export default {
  displayName: 'vendors',
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
  globals: {},
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!@smithy|uuid)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      },
    ],
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'html'],
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/vendors',
  coverageReporters: ['json', 'lcov', ['text', { skipFull: true }]],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      statements: 84,
      lines: 82,
    },
  },
};


I ran over several ChatGPT instructions but none of them seems to resolve this issue
When Im switching back to node v16 all the tests are passing
The @aws-sdk/client-ssm is up to date


I found a solution - adding the package name into the transformIgnorePatterns configuration (under jest.config file) resolved the issue. It tells to Jest to compile the package files and so the "export" error is gone.
